# Get user JAVA web app information from oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I need to write some trigger on oracle table to log user action. but I don't know how to take user info like "user_session", "user_host" and etc from java web app. I know sys_context() is be able to get my request, but as you know sys_context() doesn't work for outside database user. I don't have access to java source code or any JAR file of that app I mentioned. but I have full access to oracle DB as sysdba.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  you want information on the java client running that connects to the db?  what is "user_session?"  why can't you use sys_context()?  WHat does "doesn't work for outside database user" mean?  If you are executing a trigger, then it is running in a db session

Comment: Yes, I need to get user information from application level who connect to db. there is a table on db which contains user info like user_name and other information. according to this sentence that you said " If you are executing a trigger, then it is running in a db session", I can not use trigger for this purpose.

Comment: to clarify this issue, the db username is "scott". the other client that connect to database through "scott", when I used sys_context() in my trigger, I am be able just take "scott" information like session, host and etc has been related to "scott".

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding.  Best of luck.